# Missing KeyStore Flutter, Can not find keymap"windows Proper Redo"

Tags: flutter, keystore, sha1, keymapping

The issue is first I'm getting an error named by Missing Keymap, Can not fid keymap "Windows Proper Redo" ,search for windows proper redo keymap plugin.
And the second time this issue occurs when I'm trying to get my sha-1 key by using any method, by gradle scripts or by using command "gradlew signinReport" in terminal. It gives me the error of 'Missing KeyStore"

```
**Error in Event Log**
    Missing Keymap
                Cannot find keymap "Windows Proper Redo"
                Search for Windows Proper Redo Keymap plugin

3:48 PM 

    Run Commands using IDE: Press Ctrl+Enter to run the highlighted action using the relevant IDE feature instead of the terminal. Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter for debug. Press Enter to run the command in the terminal as usual. You can turn this behavior on/off in Settings | Tools | Terminal. Got it!
```

**Error of Missing Keystore after running command in Terminal**

```
D:\Noum\Data\Uni Data\Codes\Android Studio\Flutter\telegram\android>gradlew signinReport

> Configure project :firebase_auth
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: release
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profile
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :cloud_firestore:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :firebase_analytics:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :firebase_auth:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :firebase_core:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :firebase_messaging:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :firebase_storage:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :flutter_local_notifications:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :google_sign_in:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :image_picker:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :path_provider:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :shared_preferences:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :sqflite:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Nouma\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
14 actionable tasks: 14 executed
D:\Noum\Data\Uni Data\Codes\Android Studio\Flutter\telegram\android>
```

Comment: Make sure you can able to find the debug.keystore in the specified location ?

Comment: I'm a new user of android and flutter I don't know much about it. how to locate the debug.keystore? and what is this debug.keystore?

Comment: And if I do find the debug.keystore , what after that?

Comment: It is like a certificate that is used to generate the APK in our system PC. Without that, APK may fail to generate. You can refer the https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

for more details.

Comment: I tried this way , but I got an error=5 , Access is denied

Comment: There are many tutorials and beginner samples are available for you to kick start about Android development. 

Since you are new user, please have a look at the Stackoverflow Help Center https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking on how to ask questions. That might help you.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved!

1. I was having problem with V4.1 even after jdk 8 and v4.2 as well,
2. I made Keystores multiple times but didn't get the solution.
3. I reinstalled Adroid multiple times.
4. I deleted all the Android files from the C drive.
5. I even reinstalled my window 10.
6. I tried the signin generate jdk as well or Sign your app documentation.

Then I downloaded the latest current flutter v2.2.3 and run it with latest Android version which is currently v4.2. And now the issue of MissingKeyMap and Missing Keystore is resolved.

The above points aren't to show my effort, but it's for the others what they can try if they get stuck with this error.